# Why I get Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: android

I am facing issue of `NullPointerException`. In my app I have two classes `MainActivity` and `Test`. I am creating object main of `MainActivity` inside `Test` class. When I call display method of `MainActivity` inside `Test` class `main.display();` I get the `NullPointerException`. Please check my sample code below and recommend me changes where I am doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // Fixed
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // orientation

        setContentView(R.layout.training_ten_position);

        Test test = new Test(10);

    }


    public  MainActivity()  {
        super();
    }
    public void display() {

    }


    }



public class Test {
        .
        .
        .
        MainActivity main;

        public Test(int duration) {
            // Initializing data member
            main = new MainActivity();
        }

        public void delay() {
            .
            .
            .
            main.display();
        }
```

Comment: you should not create an instance of main activity. activity is started by `startActivity`

Comment: where is the code & logcat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do like this**

do nor create instance of **MainActivity** class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

 //Make Your Function static 

  public static void display(){
    //Do your code 
    // whatever variables or views you want to use in this method make them static
  }

}

public class Test extend Activity{
   //how call display function
   MainActivity.display();

}
```